# How to require a node.js module into cache without execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to load a node.js module into cache without execution?
I want to change require.main for testing \ debugging to the cached file and execute it later.

Comment: You mean that the constructor from a module isn't called?

Comment: Do you refer to the internal module cache? Could you please clarify your requirements? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes it refers to internal module cache. Even without code execution.  The goal is to change require.main before the new module will execute. So I need a real module instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the internal module cache: No, it is impossible. Node.js caches the exports of the module which can only be obtained by executing the module.

You might be able to intercept module execution by loading the module's code and executing it in a custom context (see [`vm` module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)). However, you will need to fix all kinds of problems which can (and will) occur. I guess it will be really ugly. This might be a possible solution, as you have complete control over the module scope. For example, you could define your own implementations of `require()`, `require.main` and `module`. I never tried this but it is the only way I can think of.

Depending on your requirements, it might be possible to just invoke a new node.js process to execute the other module (which will be `require.main`).

Answer (score 1):

Not directly but you could store the module name in a variable and create a function called executeModule `function(moduleName) {var modules[moduleName] = require(moduleName);}`

There is no real way to include the module but don't call it's constructor. A few modules require you to call it by yourself but the most have it automatically called.

Comment: This is not bad. But I need a module instance to asign to require.main before the new module code will run.